# How ignore method set_x on Action Rails 4.0 creating custom actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

have a duvid in Rails 4, because a create a custom Action called "get_json"

```rb
  def get_json

    @step_recipes = StepRecipe.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json render: @step_recipes
    end
  end
```

and add this to routes:

```rb
  get "step_recipes/get_json" => "step_recipes#get_json"
```

The problem is whit the callback in Rails 4, because i try open this route and get error `Couldn't find StepRecipe with id=get_json`,  and have this:

```rb
Parameters:

{"id"=>"get_json"}
```

I want now how i ignore this method set_x in controller , how create custom actions and no have problem whit this ? Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your routes.rb file you will likely have an entry like this somewhere above the custom route you've added for get_json:

```
resources :step_recipes
```

Amongst others, this adds a route which equates to this:

```
get "step_recipes/:id" => "step_recipes#show"
```

Since that route matches your URL first, before you have a chance of getting to your `get_json` line, it routes the request to the `#show` action and sets the `:id` param to equal `get_json`.

You will need to rename your route to something else to avoid a clash. Try this:

```
get "get_json/step_recipes" => "step_recipes#get_json"
```

You need to make sure that when adding custom routes you don't match those of any other routes that already exist.